# How to implement a service in visual studio when host of sql server and wcf are different

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, connection-string

Connection string syntax in web config when connecting to a remote host sql server.
How to write correct connection string if your  sql server host is www.xyz.com and we have a sql server instance name or we have a port number for connecting to sql server(when sql server host and service host are different).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with comma port number . My issue was in data source of connection string when we using a remote sql server. My sql server remote use port number. with adding ,port number to remote IP or host , the connection is true. ... **Data Source = www.xyz.com,1434 ;** OR Data Source = www.xyz.com\my instance name,1434 .

Answer (score 0):

It could achieve in the WCF. This is a common scenario, using WCF to `CRUD`(create,read,update,delete) the database. `Ado.net` is a common tool for persisting the data. In addition, the `Entity Framework` is also available in WCF.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/get-started
We could take advantage of server explorer in `Visual Studio`, or the SQL server object explorer. It could generate a proper connection string.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-connections?view=vs-2019
As regards the connection string, please check the following for details.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your links.My question is different. I am familiar with connection string and wcf in visual studio. I want to start a service with visual studio (self host) but I want to connect to a sql server that hosted on a host(on the web).Normally service and sql server are in same place. My goal is running a wcf service with visual studio (debugging or not debugging) and connecting to my sql server on my main host.I want to test my service with the main sql server before sending svc to main host. How to define sql server host in the connection string.(svc is not in sql server host)

Comment: I didn’t get your point. What is the difference between the WCF service running from VS and the WCF service hosted in the IIS(web server)? I think there is no difference. Assumed that we use Ado.net to connect the Database, we can connect to any database server on any network as long as we use the database connection string(if the network is unblocked).

Comment: Normally the place of a service(svc) and sql server are same.For example in your local machine you could run a wcf service(with iis or VS) when your sql server is on your machine. Now suppose your sql server in on a host(not in your machine) and you want to run your service (in your local machine) by connecting to your hosted sql server.My question exactly is about connection string writing in this situation.Writing of connection string when using of local sql in easy ans also writing of connection string when service and sql server are hosted in a host  is easy.

Comment: yeah, thereby I advise you take advantage of the Server explorer/SQL server object explorer in visual studio. it can prompt us to input the server address, the instance of the database, and the database we want to connect. after that, the connection is established, we could check the properties of the connection displayed in the Server explorer/SQL server object explorer and get the connection string.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/10163251/abraham-qian for your help.